# Duplicated data in excel using Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have created a python script that will append data in excel. However, data that are being transferred in excel is having multiple duplication. Can someone help me fix my script?

```
tree = ET.parse('users.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
#create excel
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = ("Active Users")
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=["Login", "User Name", "Role", "Status"])
for user in root.findall('user'):
    login = user.find('login').text
    for m in tls.getUserByLogin(login):
        user_status = int(m.get("isActive"))
        
        if user_status == 1:
            lastname = m.get("lastName")
            firstname = m.get("firstName")
            userLogin = m.get("login")
            activeStatus = ("Active User")
            role = m.get("globalRole")
            tproject = m.get("tprojectRoles")    
            print("Login: " + userLogin + " " + lastname + " " + firstname + " Role: " + str(role['name']) + " " + str(activeStatus))
            df.loc[len(df.index)] =[userLogin, lastname, str(role['name']), str(activeStatus)]
            for row in dataframe_to_rows(df, index = False):
                ws.append(row)          
        else:
            inactive = (str(m.get("firstName")) + " " + str(m.get("lastName")) +": User is not Active")
            print(inactive)
    wb.save(filename = 'userData.xlsx')
```

The output in excel is this:
Login = A1 , User Name = B1, Role = C1, Status = D1

1. Login User Name Role Status
2. admin Administrator Admin Active
3. Login User Name Role Status
4. admin Administrator Admin Active
5. user1 Pedro leader Active
6. Login User Name Role Status
7. admin Administrator Admin Active
8. user1 Pedro leader Active
9. user2 Juan leader Active

Also, for my else loop for inactive users, is it possible to append them in the same excel file to another sheet? Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi to @Redox and @taipei thank you for your quick responses and answers,
I have resolve my duplication issues in a different format :)

```
def getUserDetail():    
tree = ET.parse('users.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
#create excel
workbook = Workbook()
ws = workbook.active
ws.title = ("Active Users")
ws.append(['Login', 'User Name', 'Role', 'Status'])
#logins = []
for user in root.findall('user'):
    login = user.find('login').text
#    logins.append(login)
# for index in range(10):
#     login = logins[index]
    for m in tls.getUserByLogin(login):
        user_status = int(m.get("isActive"))
        if user_status == 1:
            lastname = m.get("lastName")
            firstname = m.get("firstName")
            userLogin = m.get("login")
            activeStatus = ("Active User")
            role = m.get("globalRole")
            tproject = m.get("tprojectRoles")    
            print("Login: " + userLogin + " " + lastname + " " + firstname + " Role: " + str(role['name']) + " " + str(activeStatus))
            data = [[userLogin, lastname + firstname, str(role['name']), str(activeStatus)]]
            for row in data:
                ws.append(row)
        else:
            inactive = (str(m.get("firstName")) + " " + str(m.get("lastName")) +": User is not Active")
            print(inactive)
### MOVED code here - note it should be outside ALL for loops ####             
workbook.save(filename = 'userData.xlsx')
```

getUserDetail()

Answer (score 0):

The `ws.append()` and `ws.save` should be outside of the ALL `for` loops, including the first one. Updated code here.

```
tree = ET.parse('users.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
#create excel
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = ("Active Users")
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=["Login", "User Name", "Role", "Status"])
for user in root.findall('user'):
    login = user.find('login').text
    for m in tls.getUserByLogin(login):
        user_status = int(m.get("isActive"))
        
        if user_status == 1:
            lastname = m.get("lastName")
            firstname = m.get("firstName")
            userLogin = m.get("login")
            activeStatus = ("Active User")
            role = m.get("globalRole")
            tproject = m.get("tprojectRoles")    
            print("Login: " + userLogin + " " + lastname + " " + firstname + " Role: " + str(role['name']) + " " + str(activeStatus))
            df.loc[len(df.index)] =[userLogin, lastname, str(role['name']), str(activeStatus)]
        else:
            inactive = (str(m.get("firstName")) + " " + str(m.get("lastName")) +": User is not Active")
            print(inactive)

### MOVED code here - note it should be outside ALL for loops ####
for row in dataframe_to_rows(df, index = False):
    ws.append(row)          

wb.save(filename = 'userData.xlsx')
```

Comment: Hi, I noticed that if I moved the `for row in dataframe_to_rows(df, index = False):` outside of the all for loops,I also get duplicated results because I have else statement for inactive users.

Comment: You should not. The ````else```` statement is inside the ````FOR```` loop. Also, you are not adding anything to ````DF```` for inactive users, only active users are added - ````df.loc[....````. Did the updated code not run as required? Are there duplicates in df? In the file?

Comment: from your indentation, It also does not create an excel file. But if I indent it align with `for m in tls.getUserByLogin(login):` excel file is being created

Comment: Is your code inside a function? The indentation is where the problem is. I ran this code (minus the getUser part and it runs fine. The for loop - ````for user in root.findall('user'):````, the for loop ````for row in dataframe_to_rows(df, index = False):```` and the save line ````wb.save(filename = 'userData.xlsx')```` should all be aligned exactly the same vertically (same amount of indentation).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `users.xml` only contains a unique user?

If you're not sure, I think it's better to check existing user logic.

to achieve that you can use a dictionary or array to temporary store your user in a loop and check if the current user was exists

```py
. . .
user_tmp = []
for user in root.findall('user'):
    login = user.find('login').text
    # Check if login is in the list
    if login not in user_tmp:
        user_tmp.append(login)
    else:
        # if login is in the list, continue the loop
        continue
 . . .
```

since you are using the Pandas data frame, you can generate multiple sheets when saving the data frame with [toExcel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

```py
# Example, you generate an active user in df_active and inactive user in # create a excel writer object
with pd.ExcelWriter("path to file\filename.xlsx") as writer:
    # use to_excel function and specify the sheet_name and index
    # to store the dataframe in specified sheet
    df_active.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Active", index=False)
    df_inactive.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Inactive", index=False)
```

I hope you can get hints to solve your issues from my suggestions.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, yes `users.xml` contains unique users with their login,status etc. However, I created another loop for testlink api request `getUserByLogin`  to be able to get each user's project role which is not available in `users.xml`. Let me go ahead and try to have another excel sheet from your scrpt :)